# Matching element from value list in a dictionary to another element in the same list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'm using the following: http://deron.meranda.us/data/nicknames.txt which has the nicknames for most of the names. I'm using it as follows:

```
def load_names():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as infile:
        outdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for i, line in enumerate(infile.readlines()):
            tmp = line.strip().split('\t')
            outdict[tmp[1]].append((tmp[0]))

    return dict(outdict)
```

This returns a dictionary where the actual names as keys and all their nicknames as a list of values for that key.

Now, when I have a

```
namelist = ['KEN', 'KENNY', 'KENNETH', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL', 'LIZ', 'LIZZIE', 'ELIZABETH']
```

then I want to output only the different names i.e., `['KENNETH', 'MITCHELL', 'ELIZABETH']`, which I'm able to do by:

```
l = load_names()
temp =[]
for i in namelist:
    v = l.get(i)
    if v is not None:
        l3 = [x for x in namelist if x not in v]
        temp.append(l3)

print(temp)   
s = set.intersection(*map(set,temp))     
s = list(s)
print(s)
```

However, I also want it to deal the case like `['KEN', 'KENNY', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL', 'LIZ', 'LIZZIE', 'ELIZABETH']`, this should output `['KEN', 'MITCHELL', 'ELIZABETH']` i.e., the two nicknames 'KEN' and 'KENNY' belong to the same key so, I want to consider them as one and have only one of them in the final list. Also, if I have a namelist as `['KENNETH, 'ZHAO', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL']`then it should output: `['KENNETH', 'ZHAO', 'MITCHELL']` i.e., for such names that do not occur in the dictionary at all (in either key or value), then output list should still have that name.
How do I get that?

UPATE:

```
outdict = {'KENNETH': ['KEN', 'KENNY'], 'MITCHELL': ['MITCH'], 'ELIZABETH' : ['LIZ', 'LIZZIE'], .....}

namelist1 = ['KEN', 'KENNY', 'KENNETH', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL', 'LIZ', 'LIZZIE', 'ELIZABETH']

output1 = `['KENNETH', 'MITCHELL', 'ELIZABETH']`
```

I'm getting the above output from the code I have put.

However, I want to be able to get the following outputs also when the namelists are as follows:

```
namelist2 = ['KEN', 'KENNY', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL', 'LIZ', 'LIZZIE', 'ELIZABETH']`

output2 = `['KEN', 'MITCHELL', 'ELIZABETH']`

namelist3 = ['KENNETH, 'ZHAO', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL']`
output3 =  `['KENNETH', 'ZHAO', 'MITCHELL']`
```

Got the answer myself:

```
l = load_names()
    temp =[]
    e = {}
    for n in namelist:
        if n in l.keys():
            temp.append(n)


    for ix in namelist: 
        for key, i in l.items():
            if key in namelist:
                continue
            else:
                b=0
                if ix in i:
                    b=1
                    f=0
                    for x in temp:
                        if x in i:
                            f=1
                            break
                    if f == 0:
                        temp.append(ix)
                        break
                b=0
                for k2, loc in l.items():
                    if ix in loc:
                        b=1
                        break
                    elif ix == k2:
                        b=1
                        break
                if b == 0:
                    temp.append(ix)   
                    break
    print(temp)
```

Comment: Add the "actual" names to a set?

Comment: @wmorrell What do you mean?

Comment: Instead of adding names to another list, use `set`. That's what sets are for.

Comment: When you post a question, please try to reduce it to only what's necessary. The entire first paragraph and code snippet could've been replaced by "I have a dict that maps nicknames to names" plus a small sample of that dict. If you had done that, we could just copy+paste the dict and play around with it. Now we have to download that txt file, copy your code snippet, fix the file path and run the code to get our hands on a dict to work with. It would also make your question more clear - for a while I wasn't sure if your 2nd code snippet worked as intended or not.

Comment: include your dict for clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
def getOddout(st):
    out = []
    for s in st:
        if not any([s in r for r in st if s != r]):
            out.append(s)
    return out
namelist = ['KEN', 'KENNY', 'KENNETH', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL', 'LIZ', 'LIZZIE', 'ELIZABETH']
print getOddout(namelist)
```

if its not put your dict object

Comment: Updated the question to include my dict object and the outputs that needed as well. I hope that is clearer now.

Comment: Your code isn't using the dict at all and gives wrong output completely.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lists to a dict and then returning the keys works, but there has to be a better way.

```
l = load_names()
e = {}
for k, v in l.items():
    for n in namelist:
        if n in v and k not in e:
            e[k] = v
print('dict', e.keys())
```

Outputs

```
['ELIZABETH', 'MITCHELL', 'KENNETH']
```

Comment: Right but if the namelist is ['KEN', 'KENNY', 'MITCH', 'MITCHELL', 'LIZ', 'LIZZIE', 'ELIZABETH']`

then I want the output to be `['KEN', 'MITCHELL', 'ELIZABETH']`